# Node.js - Event loop and Internal Server Errors

Tags: node.js

In a Node.js application, what happens with other requests, when a single thread throws an Internal Server Error?

Since node.js handles every request in a single process, I'm wondering what will happen.

Comment: Unless you somehow handle the internal error, the other requests will return a 500 because the Node process will shutdown...

Comment: Usually such exceptions are caught by error handling and responded to. So, the response is sent, and the callstack is cleared, allowing the next callback in the queue to be executed.

Comment: this isnt true: Since node.js handles every request in a single process, I'm wondering what will happen.  Node launch 1 process (unless clustering)

Comment: This question should be improved to include the exact scenarios under which the error happens. Clustering is one thing, domains are another thing. Without any special care, when an error happens, nothing is returned to the client (not even a 500), because the process basically crashes mid-flight.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a single treaded process, however each request is handled as a socket handle, not in a thread of its own.  Internally node waits for IO on each open socket.  If a request generates a internal server error for some reason, you just respond back with a 500.

If there is an uncaught exception (a bit different than an internal server error, but possibly what your asking about), this will affect the entire process.  You can have a built in final exception handler, but this should be used for cleaning up the process and restarting it.  All exceptions should be handled cleanly in code, you should not rely on the "uncaughtException" listener to recover the process and continue execution.